# Laravel NPM causing ELIFECYCLE

Tags: laravel, npm

I'm trying to run "npm run dev" with my Laravel project. But this keeps ending up in an error "ERR! code ELIEFECYCLE"

I've basically tried a lot of different solutions... Tried everything in this one: [laravel npm run dev ERR! code ELIFECYCLE Failed at the @ development script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53455293/laravel-npm-run-dev-err-code-elifecycle-failed-at-the-development-script)

and even followed the link in that post with no luck. I've been pulling my hair out trying to solve this...

Deleted nodes-modules A LOT. And reinstalls of NPM. Force cleared the cache. Different webpack versions and so on.. But if i try different versions I get an error saying it doesn't match API scheme version.

So now. I'm looking here for some answers/help.

This is from my command line after I ran "npm run dev"

```
#
# Fatal error in , line 0
# Check failed: U_SUCCESS(status).
#
#
#
#FailureMessage Object: 0000005E5DCFDB70npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! @ development: `cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ development script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\stito\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-28T21_34_16_881Z-debug.log
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 3221225477
npm ERR! @ dev: `npm run development`
npm ERR! Exit status 3221225477
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ dev script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\stito\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-04-28T21_34_16_900Z-debug.log
```

Log file

```
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
1 verbose cli   'C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
1 verbose cli   'run',
1 verbose cli   'dev'
1 verbose cli ]
2 info using npm@6.9.0
3 info using node@v12.0.0
4 verbose run-script [ 'predev', 'dev', 'postdev' ]
5 info lifecycle @~predev: @
6 info lifecycle @~dev: @
7 verbose lifecycle @~dev: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
8 verbose lifecycle @~dev: PATH: C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin;C:\Users\stito\Documents\Toftes IT Service\dev\toftesitservice\node_modules\.bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH\;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\dotnet\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Bitvise SSH Client;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NGX;C:\Program Files (x86)\QuickTime\QTSystem\;C:\Program Files\Common Files\Autodesk Shared\;C:\Program Files (x86)\Autodesk\Backburner\;C:\xampp\php;C:\ProgramData\ComposerSetup\bin;C:\Program Files\nodejs\;C:\Users\stito\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\stito\AppData\Roaming\Composer\vendor\bin;C:\Users\stito\AppData\Roaming\npm
9 verbose lifecycle @~dev: CWD: C:\Users\stito\Documents\Toftes IT Service\dev\toftesitservice
10 silly lifecycle @~dev: Args: [ '/d /s /c', 'npm run development' ]
11 silly lifecycle @~dev: Returned: code: 3221225477  signal: null
12 info lifecycle @~dev: Failed to exec dev script
13 verbose stack Error: @ dev: `npm run development`
13 verbose stack Exit status 3221225477
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\index.js:301:16)
13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\lib\spawn.js:55:14)
13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:196:13)
13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1000:16)
13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:267:5)
14 verbose pkgid @
15 verbose cwd C:\Users\stito\Documents\Toftes IT Service\dev\toftesitservice
16 verbose Windows_NT 10.0.17763
17 verbose argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "run" "dev"
18 verbose node v12.0.0
19 verbose npm  v6.9.0
20 error code ELIFECYCLE
21 error errno 3221225477
22 error @ dev: `npm run development`
22 error Exit status 3221225477
23 error Failed at the @ dev script.
23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
24 verbose exit [ 3221225477, true ]
```

package.json file

```
{
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "npm run development",
    "development": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "watch": "npm run development -- --watch",
    "watch-poll": "npm run watch -- --watch-poll",
    "hot": "cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js --inline --hot --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js",
    "prod": "npm run production",
    "production": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --no-progress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18",
    "bootstrap": "^4.0.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.1",
    "jquery": "^3.2",
    "laravel-mix": "^4.0.7",
    "lodash": "^4.17.5",
    "popper.js": "^1.12",
    "resolve-url-loader": "^2.3.1",
    "sass": "^1.15.2",
    "sass-loader": "^7.1.0",
    "vue": "^2.5.17",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.10"
  }
}
```

This is now solved.. I solved it by downgrading Node.js to 10.15.3 from 12.1.0

Answer (score 1):

This is now solved.. I solved it by downgrading Node.js to 10.15.3 from 12.1.0
And started from scratch with NPM in my Laravel project.

Answer (score 0):

First: check your node.js version
Write:
$ node -v

Make sure that your node.js version is up to date to the latest

If your version is cool then do the following:

- Step 1: $ npm cache clean --force
- Step 2: Delete node_modules by
  $ rm -rf node_modules ,
  $ rmdir /S /Q node_modules (in windows)
  or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete / move to trash.

If you are not updating your packages you can delete the package-lock.json file too.
$ rm ./package-lock.json
or delete it manually by going into the file and right-click > delete / move to trash.

- Step 3: npm install

To start again, $ npm start

- step 4: npm run dev

This worked for me. Hopes it works for you too.